# Could not launch “App name”, process launch failed: Unspecified?

Tags: ios, process, launch

My application gets build and compiled and just after says could not launch, process failed: unspecified. In my application target and project every thing is set to debug, I have valid development provisioning profiles too. But I don't know why this error keeps occurring every time. I have tried restarting device, code so any other suggestions other than this is appreciated.

Comment: Are you testing on device ? App should be installed on your device.

Comment: yes I am testing on device

Comment: Then app should be installed on your device. On tap you can launch the app. And if gives alert like Untrusted developer you have to go to settings and trust your app.

Comment: On the tap, it just launches the app and terminates right away so just getting a flash

Comment: are you using any privacy framework like Camera / Location / Gallery in your app and might be any chance you are running your app on iOS 10 installed device ?

Comment: If that is the scenario then it would be crashing after the application runs bacause of the usagediscription in the info.plist isn't it

Comment: Yes. If this is the scenario. check and add usage description if you are using  any one of the framework.

Comment: I have checked, its not the issue the app is crashing just after getting started

Comment: Please try to post some more error description or you didfinishlaunch code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have added question mark in title. Please see the editing help for more information on formatting. I have fixed spelling mistake which make more clear. Please, do not use thanks in advance sentence. We do appreciate your concern   Good luck!

Comment: I'm having the same issue now did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message and solved it by doing these steps:

- Unplug device
- Delete derived data
- Quit Xcode
- Start Xcode up again
- Restart the iOS device

I think the key was restarting the iOS device, but I performed the other steps as well.